# recursive delete trigger and ON DELETE CASCADE contraints are not deleting everything

Tags: database, t-sql, database-design, recursion, triggers

I have a very simple datamodel that represents a tree structure:

The `RootEntity` is the root of such a tree, it can contain children of type `ContainerEntity` and of type `AtomEntity`. The type `ContainerEntity` again can contain children of type `ContainerEntity` and of type `AtomEntity` but can not contain children of type `RootEntity`. Children are referenced in a well known order. The DB model for this is below.

My problem now is that when I delete a `RootEntity` I want all children to be deleted recursively.  I have create foreign key with CASCADE DELETE and two delete triggers for this. But it is not deleting everything, it always leaves some items in the `ContainerEntity`, `AtomEntity`, `ContainerEntity_Children` and `AtomEntity_Children` tables. Seemling beginning with the recursionlevel of 3.

```
CREATE TABLE RootEntity
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_RootEntity PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id), 
);

CREATE TABLE ContainerEntity
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_ContainerEntity PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id),    
);

CREATE TABLE AtomEntity
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_AtomEntity PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (Id), 
);

CREATE TABLE RootEntity_Children
(
    ParentId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    OrderIndex INT NOT NULL,
    ChildContainerEntityId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    ChildAtomEntityId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    ChildIsContainerEntity BIT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_RootEntity_Children 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ParentId, OrderIndex),

    -- foreign key to parent RootEntity
    CONSTRAINT FK_RootEntiry_Children__RootEntity
        FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES RootEntity (Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,

    -- foreign key to referenced (child) ContainerEntity    
    CONSTRAINT FK_RootEntiry_Children__ContainerEntity
        FOREIGN KEY (ChildContainerEntityId) REFERENCES ContainerEntity (Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,

    -- foreign key to referenced (child) AtomEntity
    CONSTRAINT FK_RootEntiry_Children__AtomEntity
        FOREIGN KEY (ChildAtomEntityId) REFERENCES AtomEntity (Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
);

CREATE TABLE ContainerEntity_Children
(
    ParentId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    OrderIndex INT NOT NULL,
    ChildContainerEntityId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    ChildAtomEntityId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    ChildIsContainerEntity BIT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_ContainerEntity_Children 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ParentId, OrderIndex),

    -- foreign key to parent ContainerEntity
    CONSTRAINT FK_ContainerEntity_Children__RootEntity
        FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES ContainerEntity (Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,

    -- foreign key to referenced (child) ContainerEntity    
    CONSTRAINT FK_ContainerEntity_Children__ContainerEntity
        FOREIGN KEY (ChildContainerEntityId) REFERENCES ContainerEntity (Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,

    -- foreign key to referenced (child) AtomEntity
    CONSTRAINT FK_ContainerEntity_Children__AtomEntity
        FOREIGN KEY (ChildAtomEntityId) REFERENCES AtomEntity (Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
);

CREATE TRIGGER Delete_RootEntity_Children ON RootEntity_Children FOR DELETE
AS
DELETE FROM ContainerEntity WHERE Id IN (SELECT ChildContainerEntityId FROM deleted)
DELETE FROM AtomEntity WHERE Id IN (SELECT ChildAtomEntityId FROM deleted)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER Delete_ContainerEntiy_Children ON ContainerEntity_Children FOR DELETE
AS
DELETE FROM ContainerEntity WHERE Id IN (SELECT ChildContainerEntityId FROM deleted)
DELETE FROM AtomEntity WHERE Id IN (SELECT ChildAtomEntityId FROM deleted)
GO
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? You have a `FOREIGN KEY (ChildStepId)` but I see no `ChildStepId`.

Comment: Have you tried to model this **without** triggers?

Comment: I have corrected the code. How can I model this **without** triggers. Wouldn't I need a way to delete the child `AtomEntity` and/or child `ContainerEntity` when a row in `ContainerEntity_Children`  or `RootEntity_Children` is deleted?

Comment: It would be rather easy without the Unique/Primary constraint: `(ParentId, OrderIndex)`. I'll have to think a bit with this included.

Comment: That key is there for two reason: 1. I thought it's good to have a PK on each table (correct me if I am wrong). 2. There must not be a duplicate (ParentId, OrderIndex) combination in the table (I am fine with contraining this without a PK somehow).

Comment: What is the setting of `RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS` option?  I guess you use SQL-Server, right?

Answer (score 1):

A try without triggers:

```
Entity
Id 
Name
PRIMARY KEY (id)

ParentEntity                  --- Root or Container
Id 
PRIMARY KEY (id)
FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Entity (Id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE

ChildEntity                   --- Container or Atom
Id
ParentId
OrderIndex 
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
UNIQUE KEY (ParentId, OrderIndex)
FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Entity (Id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES ParentEntity (Id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
```

and the rest:

```
RootEntity
Id 
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES ParentEntity (Id)         --- it is a Parent
            ON DELETE CASCADE

ContainerEntity
Id 
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES ParentEntity (Id)         --- it is a Parent
            ON DELETE CASCADE
FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES ChildEntity (Id)          --- and a Child
            ON DELETE CASCADE

AtomEntity
Id
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES ChildEntity (Id)          --- it is a Child
            ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Thanks. That'd probably work, but I was hoping to find a solution that wouldn't require big restucturing of the tables, since I would have to change a lot things in my custom/handwritten ORM mapper.

Comment: Well, I can't hel with the current design, where you have triggers that cascade deletes (and then foreign key constraints that cascade other deletes and triggers) recursively.

Comment: I still don't understand why my solution doesn't work. Should cascade delete work recusively and shouldn't a trigger be executed even when it was triggered by a cascade delete?

Comment: I can't find any error on your code but I'm not that qualified on SQL-Server to be sure.